# Jenkins in docker, workspace location

Tags: javascript, jenkins, docker

I have a Docker container running Jenkins, I can successfully build my program but I could'nt find out where it is stored.
At the end of my build I make a zip file of the JavaScript project (the dist directory) and ask to store it to /var/jenkins_home/canopy.zip , using this script

```
npm install
npm install -g bower
npm install -g grunt-cli
bower install
grunt build
zip /var/jenkins_home/canopy.zip /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Canopy/dist
```

The build is successful and in the Jenkins UI I can sucessfully see the workspace, however when I try to find it on the docker at path `/var/jenkins_home` the directory is empty.

I would like to have the location of the workspace so I can easily get back my zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it.

The directory is in the _data folder of the docker at the following path :

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes/dockerID/_data/workspace
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be found in this path as well
where the jenkins hosted to run

**PATH: /var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_home/_data/workspace**

eg:
/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_home/_data/workspace
[root@localmav workspace]# ls -lr firstjob/
total 0

here firstjob is the jenkins job